# IIS 8.5 website receiving a 404 error when trying to load images and css files

Tags: css, iis

I have new website that I just created using MVC 5. When I test it in Visual Studio it works great, the images get loaded and the css files are applied. After publishing the website and deploying it, the website can not find any of the images or css files. What seems to be different from other posts is I'm receiving a 404 file not found and not a 401 access denied. I have verified that the files are there, added IIS_IUSRS and the application pool with full access on the folders just to make sure that wasn't the issue.

The server is a Windows Server 2012 and the version of IIS is 8.5. There are about 10 other websites, of which none of them are having the same problem so it shouldn't be an issue the with static content handler.

Here is the code to display an image...

```
<div style="background-color: #495050">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <img height="150" style="margin:0px auto;display:block" src="~/Images/guru-dental-slogan-white.png">
        <hr width="800" style="color: white" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <center><strong style="color: #00B3D6; font-size: 40px">Let... </strong></center>
        <center><strong style="color: #00B3D6; font-size: 40px">Diagnosed... </strong></center>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

Root folder of the website...

[image]

What is returned from Fiddler...

[image]

What would be causing the website not to be able to access files that are there?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Without the code it will be a guess...maybe is your file path

Comment: Updated the question to include some of the code. If it's the file path why would it work while debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio understant the `~/` because is local... but the remote server cannot understand . Try this -  `src="/Images/slogan-white.png"`

Comment: I've tried that before and I just tried it again and I still cannot display the image

Comment: In your project the folder /images/ is on your root project?. Have you tried if you can see the image in your browser - http://www.yourdomain.com/Images/slogan-white.png.. If you can´t see..the folder `/Images/` is not on the root of your project or the image is real not there.

Comment: I do get a 404 when I enter the url, but the the image folder is there and so is the image.

Comment: If give that error..the image or the folder is not there...it´s a fact!

Comment: Sorry, but they are there, both the folder (as you can see) and the file is there

Comment: Is the application is a virtual directory ? Have you check the folder permissions...give to everyone for testing purposes

Comment: I've updated the question to show the folders for the website and the files in the image folder. The whole name of the image is guru-dental-slogan-white.png. It is not a virtual directory. I added "everyone" with full control and the image still cannot be found.

Comment: The image is not there... `slogan-white.png` the image is `guru-dental-slogan-white.png`

Comment: I just changed the name so it was shorter. The website is using guru-dental-slogan-white.png. In either case if you try to go to gettingstarted.gurudental.com/images/laptop.png you also receive a 404.

Comment: You must check your permissions, webconfig, routing tables, etc...